# Document python using Eclipse/Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-sphinx, pydoc

I am new to python development and use Eclipse/Pydev. Is there a nice way to integrate tools for generating documentations (e.g. Sphinx, pydoc) into the IDE to have a nice workflow, maybe showing the documentation in a separate tab?

Comment: @evaldo, did you find an answer to your question ?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the Eclipse ReST editor can help you (I heard about it in the last Eclipse demo camp held in Grenoble/France):

http://www.slideshare.net/tcalmant/rest-editor-eclipse-demo-camp-grenoble-2011

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rest-editor